# jquery http post set data to whole array, to be sent one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

Is it possible to send an array, one object at a time in AJAX post.

**what i want** :

```
$.ajax ({
  url: 'my/url/path',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json'
  data: data // whole array, send one at a time data[n+1]
  });
```

**what i have** :

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $.ajax ({
    url: 'my/url/path',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
    data: data[i]
});
}
```

Comment: i would just like to avoid the for loop if possible.

Comment: make data in json form and pass it

Answer (score 0):

Just post your array in an object.

```
$.ajax ({
  url: 'my/url/path',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {data: data}
});
```

Comment: will the success callback be called for every object or just once when the whole array is done ?

Comment: It sends the whole array. The success callback is called when the server responds.